# pandas adding new column?

Tags: python, pandas

l m learning `Pandas` and l m trying to learn things in it. However ,l got stuck in adding new column as new columns have larger index number.l would like to add more than 3 columns.

here is my code:

```
import pandas as pd
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
import numpy as np

example=pd.read_excel("C:/Users/ömer sarı/AppData/Local/Programs/Python/Python35-32/data_analysis/pydata-book-master/example.xlsx",names=["a","b","c","d","e","f","g"])

dropNan=example.dropna()
#print(dropNan)
Fillup=example.fillna(-99)
#print(Fillup)
Countt=Fillup.get_dtype_counts()
#print(Countt)
date=pd.date_range("2014-01-01","2014-01-15",freq="D")
#print(date)
mm=date.month
yy=date.year
dd=date.day
df=pd.DataFrame(example)
print(df)
x=[i for i in yy]
print(x)
df["year"]=df[x]
```

here is example dataset:

```
     a      b      c   d   e      f     g
0    1    1.0    2.0   5   3   11.0  57.0
1    2    4.0    6.0  10   6   22.0  59.0
2    3    9.0   12.0  15   9   33.0  61.0
3    4   16.0   20.0  20  12   44.0  63.0
4    5   25.0    NaN  25  15    NaN  65.0
5    6    NaN   42.0  30  18   66.0   NaN
6    7   49.0   56.0  35  21   77.0  69.0
7    8   64.0   72.0  40  24   88.0  71.0
8    9   81.0    NaN  45  27   99.0  73.0
9   10    NaN  110.0  50  30    NaN  75.0
10  11  121.0    NaN  55  33  121.0  77.0
11  12  144.0  156.0  60  36  132.0   NaN
12  13  169.0  182.0  65  39  143.0  81.0
13  14  196.0    NaN  70  42  154.0  83.0
14  15  225.0  240.0  75  45  165.0  85.0
```

here is error message:

IndexError: indices are out-of-bounds

after that ,l tried that one and l got new error:

```
df=pd.DataFrame(range(len(x)),index=x, columns=["a","b","c","d","e","f","g"])

pandas.core.common.PandasError: DataFrame constructor not properly called!
```

it is just a trial to learn and how can l add the date with split parts as new column like["date","year","month","day"....]

Comment: Doing `example.fillna(-99, inplace=True)` is sufficient. You do not need to perform `dropna` prior to this. That error is because of setting `DatetimeIndex` having a length of 147 rows compared to your `DF` which has only 15 rows currently.

Comment: yeap, l know and l want the rest of part filled with -99 or NaN .l m playing on data .how can l add a column with having larger rows?.By the way,l used dropna to see the result.

Comment: You simply can't extrapolate the old indices which are integers to take on new `datetime` values. You can only align them on a common index value.